# Возможно ли преобразовать русский формат даты в английский php?

Tags: php

Возможно ли преобразовать русский формат даты в английский средствами php ? Если да, то как?
например, 15 ноября 2018 в 15 November 2018

Comment: месяц по условию может склоняться?

Comment: @Alex нет, без склонений

Comment: из коробки нет, на массивах подойдет?

Comment: дата изначально содержит название месяца в виде "ноября", или же дата может иметь вид 15.11.2018?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно реализовать через регулярку если месяцы склоняются '/январ/'.

```
$ruMonths = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];
$enMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

$enDate=str_ireplace($ruMonths, $enMonths, '15 ноября 2018');

echo $enDate; // 15 November 2018
echo date('d M Y',strtotime($enDate)); // 15 Nov 2018
```